# Axios PUT request that updates specific value based on input name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, put

I have access to database with something simular to this :

```
{
  "entity": {
    "phone_number": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "website_url": "string",
    "country": "string",
  },

  "client_details": {
    "business_description": "string"
  },
}
```

I'm trying to send a PUT request right as a client fills up an input field. (basically onBlur)

My current idea is something like this:

```
  const updateEntity = (entityName) => {
    axios
      .put(process.env.BACKENDLINK + "/example?uuid=" + getVarByName("uuid"), {
        entity: {
          entityName: entityName
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

I'm trying to update entity based on the name of the inputFiled, for example name, phone_number etc, yet, I feel like I'm missing something, would be very grateful for your help, thanks.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: apparently there was no issue, I'm an idiot :)